# Get main element attributes of XML using LINQ

Tags: c#, xml, linq

I need to retrieve the attributes of the main node, but my code is not printing anything.

```xml
<MAINNODE AONE="22 11 12" ATWO="444"><CHILDNODE Aone="7"/></MAINNODE>
```

This is the code:

```
var listItems = xdocument.Root
.Elements("MAINNODE")
.Select(e => e.Attribute("AONE"))
.Select(a => a.Value.Split(' ').Select(s => XmlConvert.ToInt32(s)).ToList())
.ToList();
foreach (List<int> list in listItems)
{
    print(list);
}
```

I am able to get attributes of child nodes, but not of the main one. I am new to LINQ and XML.

Comment: If this is the whole XML, then `Root` is the main node and you can get its attributes through `xdocument.Root.Attributes`.

Comment: Should be : .Elements("MAINNODE")  You are missing the double quotes

Comment: Yes just edited thanks

Comment: `Elements("MAINNODE")` looks for *children* of the root node named MAINNODE

Comment: Yes Oliver its all the XML. If i delete the .Elements("MAINNODE") i get XElement does not contains a definition for Select. Can you elaborate? Thanks
If i use Root.Attributes
I get XElement .Attributes is a method wich is not valid in the given context

Comment: void Main()
{
 var xml = @"<MAINNODE AONE=""22 11 12"" ATWO=""444""><CHILDNODE Aone=""7""/></MAINNODE>";
 var listItems = XElement.Parse(xml)
 .DescendantsAndSelf("MAINNODE")
.Select(e => e.Attribute("AONE"))
.Select(a => ((string)a).Split(' '))
.SelectMany(s => s.Select(x => int.Parse(x)))
.ToList();
 foreach (var list in listItems)
 {
  Console.WriteLine(list);
 }
}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If this is the whole XML, then Root is the main node and you can get its attributes through `xdocument.Root.Attributes`:

```
string[] listItems = xdocument.Root.Attribute("AONE").Value.Split();
int[] intItems = Array.ConvertAll(listItems, s => Int32.Parse(s));
foreach (int i in intItems) {
    Console.WriteLine(i);
}
```

This will print

> 22
> 11
> 12

See also: [Array.ConvertAll<TInput,TOutput>(TInput[], Converter<TInput,TOutput>) Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.array.convertall?view=netframework-4.7.2&f1url=%3FappId%3DDev16IDEF1%26l%3DEN-US%26k%3Dk(System.Array.ConvertAll%60%602);k(TargetFrameworkMoniker-.NETFramework,Version%253Dv4.7.2);k(DevLang-csharp)%26rd%3Dtrue)

---

Note: if you need a list, you can create one from the `int[] intItems` array

```
var list =  new List<int>(intItems);
```

or, instead of converting the string array to an int array first, directly do the conversion when calling the constructor:

```
var list = new List<int>(listItems.Select(s => Int32.Parse(s)));
```

Comment: `Int32.Parse()` is localized so may not behave consistently in all locales.  `XmlConvert.ToInt32()`, conversely, is guaranteed to parse `xs:int` values correctly.